# Save data into MySQL database if value is greater than 0 using AJAX or XMLHttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form separated in three parts. Each part is dynamic and populated by data from database. For example, every item saved in database can be shown in form as `input` only if its status is 1. Also, together with selected data my PHP script generates buttons with `+` and `-` javascript function as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6sc7bok/3/)

The problem that I don't know how to resolve is how to save `name` and `value` for each input where value is greater than 0. I was wandering if some of this two `javasripts` are usable for resolving my problem?

Script 1, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRWyb/4/):

```
$('forma').submit(function(){    
    $('.qty').each(function(){ 
        if($(this).val() != '0')
        {
            $('output').text($('output').text()+ ' ' + $(this).attr('name') + ' ' + $(this).val()+ ';' );
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Script 2:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('forma').children;
var data = {};
for(var i in inputs ){
    if(inputs[i].value != 0)data[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
}
```

save.php file example:

```
<?php

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("article_db") or die(mysql_error());


 $sql="INSERT INTO article (order)
 VALUES ('".$_POST['output']."')";

 $save = mysql_query($sql);

 mysql_close();

?>
```

Script 3:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#forma').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();    
        $('.qty').each(function(){ 
           if($(this).val() != '0')
             {
                $('#output').text($('#output').text()+ ' ' + $(this).attr('name') + ' ' + $(this).val()+ ';' );
             }
          });
          var e=$(this);
          var output = document.getElementById('#output');
          var out = $(e).val();
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "save.php",
                        dataType: "json",                        
                        data: "out="+out,
                        success: function(response) {
                                if (response.ok){
                                        alert("Saved: " + response)

                                }else{
                                        alert(response.error);
                                }
                        },
                        error: function(){
                                alert("This won't gonna work like that!");
                        }
                });
        });
 });
```

and save.php:

```
<?php

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("caffe") or die(mysql_error());

 if(isset($_POST['forma'])){
 $sql="INSERT INTO narudzbe(narudzba) VALUES ('".$_POST['output']."')";

 $save = mysql_query($sql);
 }

 mysql_close();


?>
```

I am getting from first part of script 3 result on the page, but it won't save into database.

If they are, how can I do that? I have never used AJAX or XMLHttprequest for saving data into database before, only pure PHP. I need to mention that I also use `jquerymobile` for this project. I know that `mysql_connect` and `mysqli_connect` are deprecated, but this is only for exercise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: who says `mysqli_*` is deprecated?

Comment: So look at a tutorial on Ajax....

Comment: Well, it is not yet, but will bee very soon. I was looking into AJAX tutorials, but I'm kinda lost in it, can't find solution for my problem. Tried several examples but with no result. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you a bit ...

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/file',
      type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
      dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
      data: {param1: 'value1'},
    })
    .done(function() {
      console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });
```

Now.. What i usaly do when i use Ajax i create a ajax.php and inside I use isset condition... like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submitForm'])){
#php code
}
```

so in the $.ajax in data: you have to put your isset variable like so :

```
data: {submitForm: TRUE,otherdate:data}, //this is still javascript side
```

Then in the php side if you want to have access to the data used depending on the type you set you can get them as :

```
$_GET['otherdate'] OR $_POST['otherdate']
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Well, I am still stuck. By so far I created script updated in the answer as Script 3. What I'm missing? I am getting result on the page (inside paragraph with 'output' id to see if at least one part of the script works) but then I got the message from error function.

Comment: Maybe I should create button for first part of the script that passes result to the hidden input field, and another one for submitting to AJAX? For example, Save button is hidden until I press confirm order button that passes output to hidden input and unhide save button.

Comment: I think the problem is in your php file look in the jquery you start with a `e.preventDefault();` on the submit event ( which is fine because you want to trigger a Ajax call instend ) your problem is in the php isset .. `if(isset($_POST['forma'])){` which is your form ... but this is never set because you prevent the submit trigger.. what you need to do is like in the answer but the isset on the data send from the Ajax + I will recommande you to set your data like so `data: {param1: 'value1'},` then use the isset like so : `isset($_POST['param1'])`

Comment: I finally have managed to save data with some of your hints, thank you.  I have just one little problem, I can't populate input field with Script 1 as shown in the question, but I can populate paragraph with output id. If you see what I'm missing, another hint would be great. I have posted solution of my main problem as answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed solution to my problem thanks to Sebastiens hint by shown below:

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#posalji").click(function() {

var dataType = document.getElementById("dataType").value;
var output = document.getElementById("output").value;
var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: {dataType: dataType, output: output, status: status}
       })
    });
});
```

and PHP file:

```
<?php

 $dataType = $_POST['dataType'];
 $output = $_POST['output'];
 $status = $_POST['status'];

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("caffe") or die(mysql_error());


 $sql="INSERT INTO narudzbe (sto, narudzba, status) VALUES ('$dataType', '$output', '$status')";

 $save = mysql_query($sql);


 mysql_close();

 header('Location: index.php');


?>
```

Thank you Sebastien, thank you again.